# Does Hinduism teach Obsession and Exorcism?

Tags: teaching

Hinduism teaches Lokas, afterlife and spirit worlds.

Abrahamic religions teaches about spirit worlds, mainstream Islam and Christianity teaches Obsession and Exorcism.

Does Hinduism teach Obsession and Exorcism?

Comment: It does, but there are no authorised gurus who could teach the art of exorcism. Most of the pandits and tantriks have become less powerful and ignorant because they do not follow rules and regulations mentioned in the bhagvad Gita.

Comment: There are various Samhitas and Tantric books regarding the Possessions and Exorcism. The Aghora Sect who are basically Tantrik perform rituals and every other possible thing. There are various paths to learn this art but it can be dangerous, and you must have your Guru with you. I advice you consult a Pandit or a learned person.

Comment: What is "obsession"?

Answer (score 1):

In general what I found in respect of this subject was imported possession rituals from british religions and old shamanism. So, I fear vedic literature don't say anything about it, but there is yogic power of control another body...maybe this is something in that direction.